# join three tables with SQL

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

1. CLIENT table : It has a id and a name.
2. CAR table : it has its own id and the name of the car
3. CAR-owner table: it has an id_car (same as CAR ID) and id_owner(same
   as CLIENT ID)

I want to SELECT the CLIENT name, CAR name that a client owns.

I have tried this but I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
SELECT 
    CLIENT.name, CAR.name, CLIENT.id
        FROM CLIENT 
        LEFT JOIN CAR-owner ON CLIENT.id = CAR-owner.id_owner 
        LEFT JOIN CAR ON CAR.id = CAR-owner.id_car 
        WHERE CLIENT.id = ?;
```

Comment: `CAR-owner` isn't a valid identifier, it has to be delimited with back-ticks.

Comment: `owner.id`? There's no `owner` table.

Comment: @jarlh you're right, it was just a copy mistake sorry. should i put back.ticks wherever CAR-owner is written or what?

Comment: I'd instead chose a table name not needed to be delimited, e.g. `car_owner`.

Comment: @jarlh Im not sure im getting what you mean, could you please edit the query for me?, i would understand it better when its written, im not really familiar with sql yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join:

```
select cl.name client_name, ca.name car_name
from client cl
inner join car_owner co on co.id_owner = cl.id
inner join car ca on ca.id = cl.id_car
where cl.id = ?
```

I would strongly recommend against having characters such as `-` in table names. This requires quoting the indentifier everywhere you use it:

```
select cl.name client_name, ca.name car_name
from client cl
inner join `car-owner` co on co.id_owner = cl.id
inner join car ca on ca.id = cl.id_car
where cl.id = ?
```

I am unsure that you really need a `left join` here, so I used `inner join`. You can revert that if you want otherwise.

Comment: Yeah this has worked so fine thanks a lot. But why the inner join instead of the left join?, i thought i would be in need of a left join in this case